# Symfony2 - Doctrine: Redefinition of a class issue

Tags: class, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a strange kind of problem.
I'm totally new to symfony2 so forgive me if this is a silly question.

However, i'm trying to create two entities which will made persistent data onto a db and that two entities will be one for the user and one for Groups.
I've defined those two classes following a [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) and everything seems to go fine as i create only the first entity and run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` - BTW the db was alredy created!.

In a second time i've decided to create the second entity (that will have a relationship with the first, and i've decided to use doctrine notation for define that relation).

This is my *significant* code

```
 // src/Sestante/UserBundle/Entity/User.php
 [...]
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="GroupAndRoles", inversedBy="users")
 *
 */
 private $groups;
 [...]
```

and

```
// src/Sestante/UserBundle/Entity/GroupAndRoles.php
<?php

namespace Sestante\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="groups")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class GroupAndRoles implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ... getters and setters for each property

    /**
     * @see RoleInterface
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
}
?>
```

As i run once again `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` i get this error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Sestante\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\GroupAndRoles in /var/www/html/symfony/Symfony/src/Sestante/UserBundle/Entity/GroupAndRoles.php on line 13

Moreover I've tried to find from the root of my application a file where that entity could be redefined with that command `find . -type f -exec grep Sestante\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\GroupAndRoles {} \;` but no results were produced.

I suppose that i'm missing something like, maybe, cache or something related to it? (read a chapter into symfony book that told something about that, but dind't remember it weel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may just be a typo, but the file paths in the comments at the top of the file excerpts you posted differ from those in your fatal error and namespace declaration. Do you have files duplicated at `src/Sestante/UserBundle/Entity/GroupAndRoles.php` and `src/UserBundle/GroupAndRoles.php` ?

Comment: No, sorry. That was an error of mine. Now i updated the question with right path

Comment: Your answer take me to look at a good point: The namespace that i've been used was different from that where the class were declared. So, changing `namespace Sestante\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity;` to `namespace Sestante\UserBundle\Entity;` did the job. Thank you, i'll consider it as the correct answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if that was the issue after I posted the answer. It's good to know what the error message is in such a case, it might save me some confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I forgot to declare my namespace (Using Zend 1.12 and Doctrine 2). Adding the namespace declaration at the type of the file fixed my issue.